# Should 'PFA' be followed by 'is'?

Tags: grammar, articles, acronyms, email

I am a Grammarly user. When I use PFA (Please find attachment) in my emails,

> PFA the updated presentation.

It suggests I update the statement as:

> PFA is the updated presentation.

Please clarify if it's a trash suggestion.

Comment: Acronyms should be defined before use. If you have not defined PFA before use, how do you expect anyone to understand it? If you have defined it, your question is trivial. It seems unlikely you would  need to use the phrase twice in one email, so why define the acronym anyway?

Comment: @Anton, This is an email Jargon used across boards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed using "PFA" to mean "please find attach*ment,*" (and not "attached"), we can answer this by substituting it into the sentences you provide:

> 1. Please find attachment the updated presentation.
> 2. Please find attachment is the updated presentation.

As you can see, neither of these make sense. In (1), the verb "find" has two direct objects; in (2), there are two main verbs, "find" and "is."

On the other hand, if we assume that PFA stands for "please find *attached,*" we get:

> 1. Please find attached the updated presentation.
> 2. Please find attached is the updated presentation.

Now (1) is fine, and only (2) is incorrect. So "PFA the updated presentation" is the right answer.

As usual, Grammarly is not a perfectly reliable substitute for understanding. In particular, it has no way of knowing that "PFA" stands for something that includes an imperative verb; it likely assumes that PFA, like most acronyms, is short for a noun phrase.

Comment: Your answer is formally correct and deals with the question on the level of the English Language Learners site, which is where the question belongs. But you do not deal adequately with the fundamental flaw of non-definition of an acronym that is in any case probably unnecessary.

Comment: @Anton the OP says they use it commonly, and if an acronym is in common use, you don't need to define it every time it is used. Having to do so would defeat the point of common abbreviations like "cm", "am", "St", "PS", etc, and is also true of acronyms used within a company or other environment. Nothing suggests there is any ambiguity or confusion about what PFA means, just about how to use it (similarly you can know that "cm" means "centimeter" but not know how exactly to use it in text).

Comment: @stuartF Your point may is valid in some general cases (NATO, USA, UK and the ones you mention). But although the OP may use it commonly, they give no reason to suppose that the readers of their emails will be familiar with it. Are you? Am I? I never encountered this acronym. There are only 17576 possible three plain English letter acronyms and this is just one of them. It is therefore unlikely to have a unique meaning. Indeed, https://www.acronymfinder.com/PFA.html returns 98 meanings. I stick to my original viewpoint :)

Comment: I'm willing to give OP the benefit of the doubt and assume that in their location/company/industry the acronym is common. OP seems to strongly imply this and we have no reason to doubt it.

Comment: @alphabet Thanks for understanding. You are correct to assume that it is a common acronym, at least in my geographical location across all boards of corporate communication.